# Javascript - Checking if a number is closer to 2 variables

Tags: javascript

I have 12 different numbers stored in variables, like this:

```
var span1 = 8.333333333;
var span2 = 16.66666667;
var span3 = 25;
var span4 = 33.33333333;
var span5 = 41.66666667;
var span6 = 50;
var span7 = 58.33333333;
var span8 = 66.66666667;
var span9 = 75;
var span10 = 83.33333333;
var span11 = 91.66666667;
var span12 = 100;
```

I have a function which compares a div's width to its parent's width and returns a value as a percentage (minus the % sign), for example, `48.5586`. I'd like the function to check which of these span variables the result is closest to. For example, `48.5586` would return `"span6"` as it's closer to 50 than 41.666667.

Don't really know where to start with this one, any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you have twelve variables and not one array?

Comment: if these are percentages for a responsive grid don't forget that there are the gutters between the columns, and there are only 11 of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each span is 8 1/3 % more than the previous one, which is just `100/12`, you should be able to use a formula to work out which span class you need.

I worked out the following:

```
function spanClass(percentWidth) {
    return 'span' + Math.round(percentWidth / (100/12));
}
```

This gives `span6` for 48.5586.

Comment: I believe question is some kind of XY Problem, and this is the best answer :)

Comment: this doesn't quite work because he wants the closest, not the closest one above.  but it's close.

Comment: @PeterWooster Yeah, I realised that shortly after I posted it. Hence I changed it to `Math.round()` instead of `Math.ceil()`.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest difference can be found by taking the [minimum](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) of the [absolute value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) of the difference between your input number and each variable's value.

That said, you should really use a proper data structure, like an object or an array, for mapping these strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in an array, then you can sort the array on the differece between the values. The smallest differece is first in the array, so that is the closest value:

```
var spans = [
    { span: 1, value: 8.333333333 },
    { span: 2, value: 16.66666667 },
    { span: 3, value: 25 },
    { span: 4, value: 33.33333333 },
    { span: 5, value: 41.66666667 },
    { span: 6, value: 50 },
    { span: 7, value: 58.33333333 },
    { span: 8, value: 66.66666667 },
    { span: 9, value: 75 },
    { span: 10, value: 83.33333333 },
    { span: 11, value: 91.66666667 },
    { span: 12, value: 100 }
];

var value = 48.5586;

spans.sort(function(x, y){
    var a = Math.abs(value - x.value);
    var b = Math.abs(value - y.value);
    return a == b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1;
});

alert(spans[0].span);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/77Rf9/

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have array. in my code also i am converting your variables to array and then processing. Eval is bad and should not be used

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6b

```
var span1 = 8.333333333;
var span2 = 16.66666667;
var span3 = 25;
var span4 = 33.33333333;
var span5 = 41.66666667;
var span6 = 50;
var span7 = 58.33333333;
var span8 = 66.66666667;
var span9 = 75;
var span10 = 83.33333333;
var span11 = 91.66666667;
var span12 = 100;

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    eval('arr[' + i + '] = span' + (i + 1));
}


function closestTo(arr, val) {
    var closest = 10000,
        ind = -1,
        diff = 10000; // some random number
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var tmp = Math.abs(val - arr[i]);
        if (diff > tmp) {
            diff = tmp;
            closest = arr[i];
            ind = i;
        }
    }
    alert("Closesnt Number: " + closest + "\nClosest Index:" + ind + "\nclosest variable: span" + (ind + 1))
}

closestTo(arr, 50.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of a closest function in JavaScript. Moved all the spans into an object to make iterating over them easier. Just enumerate all the spans and keep the closest one.

```
var spans = {
  span1: 8.333333333,
  span2: 16.66666667,
  span3: 25,
  span4: 33.33333333,
  span5: 41.66666667,
  span6: 50,
  span7: 58.33333333,
  span8: 66.66666667,
  span9: 75,
  span10: 83.33333333,
  span11: 91.66666667,
  span12: 100
};

function closest(value) {
  var delta
    , lastMatch;

  Object.keys(spans).forEach(function (span) {
    var thisDelta;
    if (!delta) {
      lastMatch = span;
      delta = Math.abs(value - spans[span]);
    } else {
      thisDelta = Math.abs(value - spans[span]);
      if (thisDelta < delta) {
        lastMatch = span;
        delta = thisDelta;
      }
    }
  });
  return lastMatch;
}

var result = closest(48.5586);

console.log(result);
```

Here a working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fslam) example.